# Best filesystem for (slow) usb key

Tags: debian, filesystems, raspberry-pi, usb-storage, filesystem-corruption

I made a home video player with Kodi on a RaspberryPI. I plugged in a 128GB USB key to store movies on it but found it to be dead slow. I formatted it with FAT and other than the file size limit it's veey much error prone (sometimes downloaded files are corrupted). 
Before that I tried ext2 (or 3) but took something like 10 minutes for it so I reverted to FAT and I didn't use it for more than fs creation.

But now after one week running, other than the errors the FS is now read-only! I still have to investigate the logs to understand why, but it seems to me FAT is not the right way for it. Before going ext2, what is the **best** solution?

Comment: Do you know the key itself is OK? It sounds as though the key may be bad, its size may be faked, or some other issue. Are you using plain FAT, FAT16, FAT32, or something else? Some implementations of FAT32 can only support 32GB partitions as well (though, it should be theoretically capable of partitions up to 2TB).

Comment: `badblocks` stuck at 0.2% for days...